# Why does a pointer that points to an array return an address, but a pointer that points to an integer returns the integer itself

Tags: c

Why does this code return an address:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { // An example function, with its own context
int i[1] =3 ;
int *pointer;
pointer = i;
printf("%p",pointer);
return 0;
}
```

But this returns 0x3, or in other words, the integer itself?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { // An example function, with its own context
int i=3 ;
int *pointer;
pointer = i;
printf("%p",pointer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first example does not compile at all.

Comment: Note: `p` requires its argument to be of type `void*`. So, cast it to `void*`.

Comment: Both snippets invoke undefined behaviour. The second even if you cast the pointer to `void *` when passing to `printf`.

Comment: Check section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) for info about the differences between arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 3):

When `i` is an array, most of the time `i` is short for `&i[0]` i.e. a pointer to the first element. So `pointer = i;` makes `pointer` point at the first element of `i`. Note that the pointer does not point at the array (for that you'd use `pointer = &i;`, rather it points at the first element.

When `i` is an integer there is no such rule. So your program simply tries to interpret 3 as the address to point to. Any good compiler should give you a warning, which reminds you that this probably isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

When you *dereference* a pointer then the content of the referenced object is retrieved.

If you have a pointer to an `int` and you dereference it, then you get an integer value, which is stored at the address that the pointer points to.

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;

--> p retrieves the address of a
--> *p retrieves the value at the address of a
```

If you have a pointer to an array and you dereference it, then you get an address in memory, which stored at the address the array points to. The array is simply a pointer itself, and it points to the memory address of the very first element of the array.

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int *p = a;

--> a retrieves the address of the first element: 0
--> p does the same; it has a's address
```

This should explain your first example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { // An example function, with its own context
int i[1] =3 ;
int *pointer;
pointer = i;
printf("%p",pointer);
return 0;
}
```

However, your second example is not appropriate (I'd say even wrong). This is because the pointer you are printing still shows an address and not an integer. You merely used the integer to store its value 3 in that pointer as an address. I believe this is **undefined behaviour**. Try to dereference the pointer and see if you can make sense out of it; you can't and you're program might crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { // An example function, with its own context
int i=3 ;
int *pointer;
pointer = i;
printf("%p",pointer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Olaf Exactly, that is correct. Though I don't see how you are helping here.

Comment: Without any offence: I had the same thouight reading your answer. Read the question and my comment, then your answer **carefully**.

Comment: I see what you mean. Though what I was trying to do was as follows:
I *explain* to the reader what *dereference* is; then I give examples; and then I analyse the OP's code snippets. Finally I challenge the OP to make his second code snippet crash to show it is a *corrupt*.
Maybe a strange approach, though I am not sure how to improve my answer without changing the structure of it.
Or maybe I don't really see what you mean :-(

Comment: You just pointed out another problem: undefined behaviour is undefined. There is no use trying what happens. Read other questions (and comments) from beginners; they often insist expecting a specific behaviour ("but the code works, so it can't be undefined ...").

Answer (score 0):

To the compiler, an array name is an address. That is why in the first code just using the array name `i` was enough to return the memory address to the pointer. With variables however an `&` is required in front of the variable name to return the memory address of the variable to the pointer. Thus in the second code just writing `pointer = i;` isn't enough but rather should be `pointer = &i;`

But I think why you got an output of 3 was because the pointer considered the 3 that was stored in `i` as the address to point to.